# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x

I will give you my python code (it's pretty basic and small) and if you can tell me where I am wrong. Thanks a lot and don't hate :)

```
ekt=[]
pl=[]
nm=[]
for i in range(5):
    nms=raw_input("Ποιο το όνομα της χώρας?")
    ekts=input("Ποια η εκταση της χώρας αυτής?")
    pls=input("Ποιός είναι ο πληθυσμός της χώρας αυτής?")
    nms.append(ekt)
    ekts.append(ekt)
    nms.append(nm)
max_ekts=-2
min_pls=-2
for i in range(5):
    if ekt[i]>max_ekts:
        max_ekts=ekt[i]
        max_ekts_nm=nm[i]
    if pl[i]>min_pls:
        min_pls=pl[i]
        min_pls_nm=nm[i]
    sum_pls=sum_pls+pl[i]
mo_pls=max_pls/5.0
print"Χώρα με την μεγαλύτερη έκταση:",max_ekts_nm
print"χώρα με το μικρότερο πληθυσμό:",min_pls_nm
print"O μέσος όρο του πληθυσμού των 15 χωρών της Ευρωπαϊκής Ένωσης:",mo_pls
```

the error is that : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: You cannot append to a string, you must do so to a list object.

Comment: `ekts += ekt` <- you can't append to a string because they're immutable. You can however combine two strings to create a new one and assign that back to a var. `+=` does that.

Comment: Or if `ekts` is supposed to be a list, do this, `ekts = []` and append to it with `ekts.append(input(...))`.

Comment: You have several mistakes related to variable names in your code. Please consider reviewing your code carefully before submitting a question. I read your code carefully to understand what you are trying to achieve, I notice you added an "s" at the end of your variables' names to denote which ones are strings and then, below, you treated those variables as lists. I think you just didn't notice that you tried to append to the wrong object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error ir pretty simple, look, although at the beginning of your code you declare the following lists:

```
ekt=[]
pl=[]
nm=[]
```

The next thing you do is to use those very same variable names to capture your input:

```
nms=raw_input("Ποιο το όνομα της χώρας?")
ekts=input("Ποια η εκταση της χώρας αυτής?")
pls=input("Ποιός είναι ο πληθυσμός της χώρας αυτής?")
```

But you are not doing append over your original lists, this is how your code looks like:

```
nms.append(ekt)
ekts.append(ekt)
nms.append(nm)
```

But `nms` is not the original list, your original list is called `nm`, `nms` is the string you just read. also `ekt`, the value you are trying to append, is not the string you read (which is called `ekts`), `ekt` is the list you declare at the beginning of your code. So basically you trying to append a list to a string object, which can't be done. Same thing applies to the lines bellow that one, please re-check your variables' names.

Comment: yeah, i found it myself too this stupid error,thanks a lot buddy!!! ;D

Answer (score 0):

When you read input from the user it is of type string -

```
nms=raw_input("Ποιο το όνομα της χώρας?")
```

`nms` is string. Afterward, you try to append it `nms.append(ekt)` but string type does not have append. I guess what you meant is `nm.append(nms)`.

Comment: So when i try to append a string,thats not possible?

Comment: The question is what you want to achieve. If you want to contact two strings you can use `+`. e.g `s='hello' + 'world`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i fixed my code,its kinda working actually,take a look! I tried using .append on strings input and it works!!`

```
ekt=[]
pl=[]
nm=[]
for i in range(5):
    nms=raw_input("Ποιο το όνομα της χώρας?")
    ekts=input("Ποια η εκταση της χώρας αυτής?")
    pls=input("Ποιός είναι ο πληθυσμός της χώρας αυτής?")
    ekt.append(ekts)
    pl.append(pls)
    nm.append(nms)
max_ekts=-2
min_pls=-2
sum_pls=0
for i in range(5):
    if ekt[i]>max_ekts:
        max_ekts=ekt[i]
        max_ekts_nm=nm[i]
    if pl[i]>min_pls:
        min_pls=pl[i]
        min_pls_nm=nm[i]
    sum_pls=sum_pls+pl[i]
mo_pls=sum_pls/5.0
print"Χώρα με την μεγαλύτερη έκταση:",max_ekts_nm
print"χώρα με το μικρότερο πληθυσμό:",min_pls_nm
print"O μέσος όρο του πληθυσμού των 15 χωρών της Ευρωπαϊκής Ένωσης:",mo_pls
```

I will consider in the future using +=